# Error searching *n@domain* in apache solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene

**Field Defination**

```
<field name="email" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

**Query**

```
email : "*n@domain*"
```

**Result**

No Data.

My question is that I actually have data indexed in solr matching to my criteria. But its not reflecting in query results. Is there some issue with my query pattern.

Comment: Ok. And your question is...?

Comment: Please *add that to the question* - questions should be able to stand on their own without important information (such as what the actual question is) being left to comments as an afterthought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't have the text `*n@domain*` in you're field.  Rather you have `n@domain` somewhere in the middle of a term (or so you believe).  There are a few problems you are likely to run into.  I will assume your field uses `StandardAnalyzer`.

First, no wildcards in phrase queries.  `field:"query terms"` is a phrase query, meaning a match can span multiple (post-analysis) terms.  Query parser syntax does not include any support of wildcards in phrase queries.  As such that asterisks in your query were just that, literal asterisks.

Second, now you are searching for `email:*n@domain*`, much better, but still no luck.  Wildcard queries bypass analysis, and chances are your email is analyzed in the index.  For an entry like: "test@domain.com", you actually probably ave three terms "test", "domain" and "com".  You can make the field un-analyzed to search like what you have indicated here, but that's really up to you to determine if that is the correct approach.

Once you've got that worked out, you may have something working, but may notice that performance if terrible.  Leading wildcard are often disabled by default, because they lead to awful performance, since they require a linear scan of all terms in order to enumerate matches, rather than making effective use of the index.  There are strategies to allow leading wildcards without the brutal hit to performance, such as [`ReversedWildcardFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_8_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/analysis/ReversedWildcardFilter.html)

Comment: Just a small update. Since 4.8 it is possible to use wildcard in phrases. Cwiki documentation is not up-to-date according to [SOLR-5926](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5926), but some documentation can be found at old wiki [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ComplexPhraseQueryParser).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes in your query and it should work.

The query string `email:*n@domain*` is parsed into a WildcardQuery, which is what you want.

The query string `email:"*n@domain*"` is parsed into a PhraseQuery with two terms, `email:n` and `email:domain`, instead. Notice that the wildcard characters are actually removed, and the phrase is tokenized.

Why? According to Apache Solr Reference Guide 4.8, p. 180, "Wildcard characters can be applied to single terms, but not to search phrases." By putting quotes in your query, you are telling Solr to search the quoted phrase instead of treating the unquoted string as one word.